# Data is being removed from my radeditor boxes when the datepicker is used asp.net

Tags: asp.net, telerik

I have 6 textboxes in my asp.net page which used to work fine.  They have now been changed to be telerik RadEditor boxes.  This is all working well excpet that when you scroll further down the page and select a date field using the telerik datepicker all of the information in the 6 telerik RadEditor boxes disappears.

Helppppppp.....

It used to work fine when they were normal text boxes.

```
        tbxRiskDesc.Attributes.Add("onchange", "setDirty();");
```

Now that they are RadEditor boxes the setDirty() function does not seem to work.

```
        RadEditorRiskDesc.Attributes.Add("onchange", "setDirty();");
```

The aspx code is as follows:

```
                <td class="fieldLabel" >
                    <asp:label id="lblRiskDesc" runat="server">Risk Description or Improvement Opportunities</asp:label>
                    <a href="javascript:help_create('Risk_Description')"> <img alt="" src="images/question_mark_icon.gif" border="0" /> </a>
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<br />
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="vldRiskDesc" runat="server" ControlToValidate="RadEditorRiskDesc" ValidationGroup="Risk" 
                        ErrorMessage="Risk Description must be entered" Font-Bold="True" Display="Dynamic" EnableClientScript="False">
                        Risk description must be entered</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <telerik:radeditor runat="server" ID="RadEditorRiskDesc" Height="200px" SkinID="MinimalSetOfTools" ToolsFile="~/RadControls/Editor/ToolsFile.xml" EditModes="Design" SpellCheckSettings-DictionaryPath="~/RadControls/Spell/TDF/">
                    </telerik:radeditor>                        
                </td>
```

The aspx.cs code is as follows:

```
Page_Load
        //tbxRiskDesc.Attributes.Add("onchange", "setDirty();");
        RadEditorRiskDesc.Attributes.Add("onchange", "setDirty();");

ResetData
            //SetTextCurrentValue(tbxRiskDesc, dtEditTable, "RiskDesc");
            RadEditorRiskDesc.Content = dtEditTable.Rows[0]["RiskDesc"].ToString();

ClearData
        //SetTextValue(tbxRiskDesc, "RISK TITLE & DESC.:");
        RadEditorRiskDesc.Content = "RISK TITLE & DESC.:";

SaveData
       string[] newvalue = new string[]
           {ddlSource.SelectedItem.Value,
            ddlQualityStd.SelectedItem.Value,
            tbxLocationID.Text,
            ddlRiskCategory.SelectedItem.Value.ToString(),
            bscobjective_id,
            RadEditorRiskDesc.Content,
            //tbxRiskDesc.Text,......

       DAL.UpdateEditHistory(
              historyID,
              EditDate.ToString(),
              ddlSource.SelectedItem.Value,
              ddlQualityStd.SelectedItem.Value,
              tbxLocationID.Text,
              ddlRiskCategory.SelectedItem.Value,
              bscobjective_id,
              RadEditorRiskDesc.Content.Replace("'", string.Empty).Replace(",", string.Empty).Replace(quote, string.Empty), 
              //tbxRiskDesc.Text.Replace("'", string.Empty).Replace(",", string.Empty).Replace(quote, string.Empty),......
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need to know when the content of the editors changes. This should be done by adding the needed handler to the content area as shown here: http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/editor-attacheventhandler.html. I suppose the keyup event will work for you.